# Where do you get the Black Hole spell?

Tags: candy-box-2

Is it in a grimoire with other spells? Or do you have to defeat someone/something to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Magical_purple_shark_fin), the Magical Purple Shark Fin (obtained by killing the purple-finned shark) grants the Black Hole spell.